# How to upload single file into theme

Tags: sxa, media-library

I wanted to change one `js` file from theme so I downloaded it.

[image]

Now when I made those changes I am not able to see any option to upload it. Can someone please guide me on this?

**Update**
As Raman suggested I went to the file directly but there is no download option in Media field as shown in the image. How can I see file to download.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a change in the JS file,

1. Go to that particular JS item and select it. You'll see the option to download the file.
   [image]
2. Open the downloaded file, make changes and save it.
3. Now go to the same item again in Sitecore and click on attach and select this file to upload.
   [image]
   **Note**: You should not directly make changes in the Optimized JS file, this file is auto-generated based on other uploaded JS files.

Comment: Thank you for the response Raman. I followed steps as suggested by I can't see download option under Media. I have updated the image in my question.

Comment: I am pretty much sure, you have selected the raw values option. Go to View Tab in ribbon and uncheck the Raw value option. Then follow the above steps

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Thank you so much.